# how to bind the string vlaues from array to uibutton ( static )

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

From the response i will get the array like :

```
data = ["1","2","3"]

Button1   // all uibutton iboutlet
Button2   // all uibutton iboutlet
Button3   // all uibutton iboutlet
```

Now how i will bind the data value to all the 3 button. So that in screen it have to display like ;

```
1
2
3
```

Note : All buttons are static, and only 3 data will get from response.

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 3):

```
zip([Button1, Button2, Button3], data).forEach { (button, title) in
    button.setTitle(title, for: .normal)
}
```

`zip` joins two arrays together in parallel, so the zip of `data` and `[Button1, Button2, Button3]` will be an array of tuples, like so:

```
[(Button1, "1"), (Button2, "2"), (Button3, "3")]
```

Then simply iterate the array of tuples, setting each button's title attribute to its corresponding title value.

If `data` were to have more than 3 elements, the `forEach` would still only iterate 3 times.

Answer (score 0):

Hope I have correctly understood, what do you want to do.

Try to make it like this:

```
Button1.setTitle(data[0], for: .normal)
Button2.setTitle(data[1], for: .normal)
Button3.setTitle(data[2], for: .normal)
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Type 'Any?' has no subscript members

Comment: @hybridDev on data?

Comment: @hybridDev have your created data this way: let data = ["1", "2", "3"] ?

Comment: from server i m getting like` "data": [
"989",
"908i",
"ui787"
] `

Comment: @hybridDev try to manually set data array like I have typed. Test with it. If no error, you will need to fix second problem. As I can see, your data array is not [String] type.

Comment: As I can see, your data array is not [String] type.....then how do i appen to button title ?

Comment: you need to convert your source array from as I believe [Any?] to [String]. Like let dataStrings = data as! [String]. Then use dataStrings[...] to init button titles. Or just rewrite func of getting data from server to let it return [String]

Comment: @hybridDev has it helped?

Answer (score 0):

As vlad said:

```
Button1.setTitle(data[0], for: .normal)
Button2.setTitle(data[1], for: .normal)
Button3.setTitle(data[2], for: .normal) //Notice !setTitle!
```

I also recommend to have a look at https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html

Answer (score 0):

**Make array of your Button and title**

```
let button = [button1,button2,button3]
let title = ["1","2","3"]
      for (button,title) in zip(button,title){
         button.setTitle(title, for: .normal)
      }
```